# Gracefully handle "This browser does not support WebAssembly."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

When using old devices, like old ipads etc, or internet exporer, Blazor/WebAssembly doesn't run (which is expected).  But the only message that appears is in the console saying

```
This browser does not support WebAssembly.
```

Is there an obvious/included way to handle this and inform the user, or would additional javascript need to be written to detect that?

Comment: You can check for browser version in advance within the javascript and display the custom errors to the end-user.

Comment: So that would need additional JS presumably (beyond what exists in the blazor framework)?

Comment: Yes, it needs additional customization based on your needs.